# How can I mount a ReiserFS partition on Mac OSX?

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, filesystems, macfuse

I'm on a machine running OSX Leopard and Ubuntu 10.04: Ubuntu is installed on a ReiserFS partition, and it's data as well.

Ubuntu and OSX are installed one for disk (disk0s* OSX - disk1s* Ubuntu)

I'm aware of MacFUSE and I've already used it for sshFS but now I need it to mount a ReiserFS disk: do you know how to do that?

Comment: Unlikely - the only FS I know ported outside Linux is ext*. ReiserFS is unlikely to be ported because the developers are focused on the new Reiser filesystem - Reiser4. ReiserFS has been, for all intents and purposes, abandoned by developers.

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot be mounted.  Check [here](http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-operating-system/103414-reiserfs.html) and [here](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/lofiversion/index.php/t10131.html).

You can still get to your data in a round-about way:

- Download VirtualBox and install Ubuntu to it
- Mount ReiserFS in the virtual machine
- Make a samba share in the virtual machine
- Access the Samba share in Mac OS

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly mounting the reiserfs on the same machine, another way is to have two machine:   linux running reiserfs, and NFSd, and then MacOSX running just the NFS client and mount it over the network via NFS protocol.

Similarly you can use SAMBA to share and to mount as well.